# I need to change the disabled attribute with JavaScript once the user has chosen an option on the AutoComplete input type text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is easy but for me is complicated. The thing is that I need to check if user has chosen an option on an autocomplete input text, and if the input is not blank then I want to activate a button to submit or something like it.

I have base of the logic, but It doesn't work and I don't know why.
Please, suggest me something, I am 25 years old and I am getting desesperate because I want to be a good programmer but I am not able to write good programs by myself.

Here's the code:

```
<input type="text" id="options-select">
```

The JavaScript:

```
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC"
    ];
    $( "#options-select" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: // I don't know what to put in here...
    });
  } );
```

The HTML button:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
```

Thank you and blessings.

Comment: Usually it would be a callback function which would be called with at least an argument. The web developer console is your best friend if you want to improve yourself. You can try to pass in `function() {console.log(this, arguments);}` to find out what is `this` inside the function scope and what are the arguments passed to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `change/select` event to enable/disable the button.

**Example:**

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC"
    ];
    $("#options-select").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        change: function () {
            $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:

```js
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                // change: function(eveny) {
                //     console.log("change:", event.target.value);
                // },
                select: function(event) {
                    if (event.target.value != '') {
                        console.log("Select:", event.target.value);
                        $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
                    } else {
                        $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:/resources/demos/style.css">
  <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
        <input id="tags">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
```

Comment: Practice. read the documentation of the specific language.